# Using Entity Framework what is the difference between Cascade and ClientCascade?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I am learning C# and how to use Entity Framework. I believe that I know what is Cascade, Restrict, NoAction and SetNull behaviors.

But there are other behaviors with the prefix Client:

[image]

I would like to understand what are the difference between them and when should I use ClientCascade instead of Cascade or ClientNoAction instead of NoAction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the short answer is-- when `dependent/ref. entities` are `loaded/cached` in memory, the `cascade delete` action `fails` on the main entity - because a `CYCLIC ref. LOCK`.

`ClientCascade` allows the `DBContext` to delete entities even if there is a `CYCLIC ref. LOCK`

[image: EF Core Cascades vs. Client Cascades Delete]

Answer (score 1):

The Context deletes the entities it tracks, when we delete the parent.

Cascade option creates a migration script with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, while `ClientCascade` creates a migration script with `ON DELETE NO ACTION`.

Cascade is the default behavior, when using the required relationship i.e `Foreign key` is Not Nullable

Untracked entities if any are deleted if the `ON DELETE CASCADE` is setup in the database. If not results in a `FOREIGN KEY violation`.

Not all databases support Cascade or does not support fully. Especially if there are cycles in relationships. Use `ClientCascade` and load all related entities before deleting the parent. The context will perform the Cascade Delete on the client-side.

also read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: "load all related entities before deleting the parent". `context.Remove(context.MyEntity.Include(x=>x.RelatedEntity).First());` Correct me if I am wrong. So if I didn't have the include , the relatedEntity will not be deleted.